# Compare rows values of same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, mariadb

I have data like this:

```
header_id | class | start_date | end_date
-------------------------------------------
1         | c1    | 20-08-2019 | 22-08-2019
1         | c1    | 22-08-2019 | 24-08-2019
1         | c2    | 24-08-2019 | 27-08-2019
2         | c3    | 25-08-2019 | 26-08-2019
2         | c3    | 26-08-2019 | 30-08-2019
3         | c1    | 23-08-2019 | 26-08-2019
```

I want to get the following results:

```
header_id | class | start_date | end_date
-------------------------------------------
1         | c1    | 20-08-2019 | 24-08-2019
1         | c2    | 24-08-2019 | 27-08-2019
2         | c3    | 25-08-2019 | 30-08-2019
3         | c1    | 23-08-2019 | 26-08-2019
```

Is there a way to get that result ?

Comment: Use dates in the format `2019-12-31`, else comparing, taking min/max, etc will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form what I understood, you need something like this:

```
select header_id. class, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from your_table_name
group by header_id, class
```

Change `your_table_name` to the actual name